# jsf:rendered in passthrough <li> has no effect, it still renders its output

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, passthrough-elements

I am doing a page that will show some components if the Staff is an Admin.

I am using html5 with bootstrap with primefaces 5.0

Based on what I know in JSF, you can control whether to render a component by using the rendered attribute.

Since my component is in html5, I used the jsf:rendered instead.

For my code, I used `jsf:rendered="#{staffBean.staff.accountStatus =='ADMIN'}"` and the value inside staffBean.staff.accountStatus is not ADMIN.

I have attached part of my code below.

```
<li class="active" jsf:rendered="#{staffBean.staff.accountStatus =='ADMIN'}">
    <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span class="nav-label">Account Management</span> <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
        <li class="active"><a href="createStaff.xhtml">Create Staff</a></li>
        <li><a href="removeStaff.xhtml">Delete Staff</a></li>
        <li><a href="updateStaff.xhtml">Update Staff</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Any idea on why my `jsf:rendered="#{staffBean.staff.accountStatus =='ADMIN'}"` still renders component's output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `<li>` is nowhere registered as an existing JSF component. JSF passthrough elements works only on elements which also have a JSF component equivalent, such as `<form>`, `<input>`, `<a>`, etc (which have `<h:form>`, `<h:inputText>`, `<h:xxxLink>` equivalents). They are namely "under the covers" converted to true JSF components.

Better use `<ui:fragment>` instead.

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{staffBean.staff.accountStatus eq 'ADMIN'}">
    <li class="active">
        ...
    </li>
</ui:fragment>
```

#### See also:

- [Jakarta EE tutorial - Using passthrough elements](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/jsf-facelets009.html#sthref33) - contains a table which elements have JSF component equivalents

Comment: Broken link. Try this: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets009.htm

Comment: @neo7bf: Fixed, thanks. Note that JEE is not from Oracle anymore. So your link will in long term also die.